# Why use Events when notification possible with Delegates

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I did two sample projects (links to executable code) after watching a tutorial. One [Without Event](http://rextester.com/GUWKL62440) using delegate as property and one [With Events](http://rextester.com/UXNEA69727). I get the same output when used without events.  I can also subscribe/unsubscribe to notification in both cases.

What is the benefit of using `event` taking my sample code as an example?

Comment: Yes.Mentioned thread has answers I was looking for. To summarize for my brains's sake.
1.Controlling access to the delegate (analogous to Field-Property)
2.Event provides more semantics to the class or user using the class
3.Helps with Synchronization in multi-threading

Comment: **IMPORTANT** Another obvious reason I realized was that if I use `delegate` as property then I can mess around with the Invocation List by just assigning (=) it to another method or null perhaps rather than adding (+=) or removing (-=). But `event` will enforce me to add or remove ONLY thus, preserving the Invocation list.

Comment: [Sample Code](http://rextester.com/ZTHBRI54970) to convey my meaning as mentioned above.